# Add delimiters to Out-File

Tags: powershell

No, I cannot use Export-CSV for this. =)

**The Question**: How can I add custom column delimiters when using `Out-File`?

**The Reason**: I essentially have a multithreaded PowerShell script pulling information exporting it to a file. Using `Out-File` works because it does not lock the file and nothing needs to be in order. However, I need to be able to open this in Excel eventually. My idea is to somehow export the data using `Out-File` with a special delimiter so that I can open it in excel.

I've been researching for over an hour and every similar question to mine was "solved" with people saying to use `Export-CSV` which I can not do.

**Some things I've tried**

```
foreach($item in $info){
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
FolderName = "$($item.Feature1) #"
Owner = "$($item.Feature2) #"
AccessRights = "$($item.Feature3) #"
} | ft -hide | Out-File C:\Test.txt
```

Using `#` as the special delimiter, but that leaves a million blank lines.

I've also tried things similar to:

```
| Select Feature1, Feature2, Feature3 | %{"$($_.Feature1)#", "$($_.Feature2)#", $_.Feature3} | out-file C:\Test.txt -Force -Append
```

But that goes through and expands properties that I don't want expanded.

If this is not the best way to go about this, I'm definitely open to helpful and feasible suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use `Export-CSV`?  You've intentionally limited yourself and are making life harder without reason

Comment: When you write to a file, the file is locked to other processes, anyway. If you've got multiple processes "taking turns at random" writing to this file, you can still use `Export-CSV`; as soon as you have the object, export it, with the `-Append` switch. When the export of the object is done, `Export-CSV` closes and releases the file.

Comment: `Export-CSV` fails in a matter of seconds, that's the first thing that I tried. Please if you can offer suggestions for a better way to export info from 10+ threads running concurrently I'm more than happy to hear it. I've been stuck on this for quite a while.

Comment: Output separate temporary CSV files for each thread, import them _en masse_, export them to a new CSV file, then delete the temporary files.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I hadn't thought about doing it that way, but that sounds perfect! I'll give it a shot tonight. If you want to post your comment as the answer preemptively, assuming that it works for me I'll accept it tomorrow. Thank you!  :)

Comment: Posted an answer with one possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to export a csv file for each thread -- Use something unique such as `"temp_{0}.csv" -f [Guid]::NewGuid().Guid` for the file names to prevent collisions. Once your threads are complete, do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem temp_*.csv |
  ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName } |
  Export-Csv BigOutputFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Make sure that the `Get-ChildItem` filename spec doesn't collide with the output filename spec. Then delete `temp_*.csv`.

Comment: PowerShell 5 has `New-TemporaryFile` that could be used

Comment: Yes, possibly, if the OP doesn't mind the files getting written to `$Env:Temp`.

Comment: As always @Bill_Stewart , you are awesome. This worked PERFECTLY, thank you so much!!

Comment: A sound approach, but I suggest changing `Get-ChildItem temp_*.csv |
  ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName }` to `Import-Csv (Get-Item temp_*.csv)` for efficiency. (_Piping_ `Get-Item` / `Get-ChildItem` output directly to `Import-Csv` doesn't work due to a [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4473), as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.0-beta.4 - and [neither does using wildcards](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4472) directly.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that jumps to my mind is a little convoluted but would work. Run your code through your foreach loop and create an array of Strings. Add your delimiters inside each string as it goes through the foreach loop and then output the array.

This would let you have the delimiter without using `export-csv`.